# % of Yes by Month on Pivot Table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I was wondering if it is possible to have a radar graph show the % of yes by month in this file I have created below. I tried on the right, but I can't seem to get it.

Any help is appreciated!

http://www.filedropper.com/example_6

EDIT:
The source data looks like this:

```
+-----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   Date    | Title 1 | Title 2 | Title 3 | Title 4 | Title 5 |
+-----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| June      | Yes     |         |         |         |         |
| June      | Yes     | No      |         | No      | No      |
| July      | Yes     | No      | Yes     | No      | Yes     |
| July      | Yes     | Yes     |         | Yes     | Yes     |
| August    | Yes     | No      |         | No      | No      |
| August    | Yes     | No      |         | No      | No      |
| September | Yes     | Yes     | No      | No      | Yes     |
| December  | Yes     | Yes     |         | Yes     | Yes     |
+-----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd normalise your base data so that you have three columns Date, Title (holds values 1 to 5) and Response (holds values Yes or No). Then you'll be able to create a pivot table that shows coutns of Yes and No for each Title. Then go to Value Field Settings in the pivot table and choose `Show Values As` `% Of Row Total`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! One thing that I can't change is how the original data is laid out. I have a .hta survey that populates the excel file in this format.

Is it still possible to get the % of Yes without reformating the base data?

I tried % of column total, but that only returns 100% when there are no blanks. Again I appreciate your help in this matter.

Comment: I also found something called "calculated fields." Could this help me with my problem?

Comment: @Deep The best approach would be what Matt pointed out and *Calculated Field* is not applicable to your data I guess. But if you just want to count the % Yes per month, then that is possible using formula.

Answer (score 0):

Given the response to my previous answer: that the shape of the source data cannot be adjusted, here is a second suggestion:

I'm going to suppose that the source data is in cols A:E on a sheet called "Data".

Start a new sheet like this:

```
+---+--------+-----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
|   |   A    |                    B                    |                   C                    |
+---+--------+-----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
| 1 | date   | Title 1 Yes                             | Title 1 No                             |
| 2 | June   | =countifs(Data!a:a,a2,Data!b:b,"Yes")   | =countifs(Data!a:a,a2,Data!b:b,"No")   |
| 3 | July   |                                         |                                        |
| 4 | August |                                         |                                        |
+---+--------+-----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
```

You'll need similar pairs of columns for Title 2 to Title 5, and then copy downwards the formulae in row 2.

Does that give you the sort of data you can then graph in the way you need?